# How to begin with Android Programming?

Tags: android

I'm an ASP Developer for a 2 years. now, i want to start with Android, but i don't know the essential of Android and have some questions about these as you seen below:

1. What is the best reference to starting with Android?
2. What is the best IDE to developing Android and testing the Android softwares. (my mobile is    Nokia E-52 based on 'Symbian s60 v3' and i cannot test these Android softwares on a mobile platform)
3. I want to starting Android on Windows

---

Big Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Visit http://developer.android.com/ You will get every information there..

Comment: You can try to search before ask. This question is broad. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=start+android+programming)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the best reference to starting with Android?

You can start with [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/). It is very good where you can start Android.

> What is the best IDE to developing Android and testing the Android softwares.

Eclipse IDE is best for android development and for testing you need not to buy any device at starting, you can use emulator for testing. Once you have done with training you may choose any Android device depending on your requirements.

Joining following groups might also help:

- [Android UI Design](https://www.facebook.com/groups/AndroidUI/) (on FB)
- [Android group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/andorid/) (on FB)

Comment: Thanks! It is a big help.

Answer (score 1):

I find this tutorial very good to start with Android: http://www.kilobolt.com/android-application-development-tutorial.html.

Official Google IDE for Android: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html (IntelliJ IDEA bundle). You can also use Eclipse and its Android plugin.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best reference to starting with Android?

Start in [Android](http://developer.android.com) Developer website and get to know the basic API. You can also search in Youtube is a good source of hundreds if not thousands of tutorials relate to Android SDK.

> What is the best IDE to developing Android and testing the Android
>   softwares?

You can use either Eclipse, a great IDE for java/android SDK, or the new [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) provided by google which I think is promising.

> my mobile is Nokia E-52 based on 'Symbian s60 v3' and i cannot test
>   these Android softwares on a mobile platform

Beside the slow emulator provided by the SDK there is a good alternative and is [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/).

Get Started Today -> [SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) & [First Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z149x12sXsw)

Wish you the best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I too am new to Android and I managed to get good enough knowledge from android official guide. It has all details starting from how to install SDK. This is the link : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html

I'm using eclipse as the IDE and you can use emulator there for testing (AVD), if you don't have a proper testing device to test.

It doesn't matter what the OS is. So you can use Windows for developing.